# Electron webview events

Tags: events, webview, electron

I'm writing an app in electron and came across with some issues, appreciate if anyone can help.

I'm navigating a webview to `src="about:blank"`

and load it with

```
var urlOptions = {
    extraHeaders: 'Authorization: Bearer ' + arg.token
};
webview.loadURL(arg.viewToLoad, urlOptions);
```

Then, when the `dom-ready` event is triggered, I'm calling

```
webview.addEventListener('did-finish-load', () => spiner.hide());
```

I'm trying to make a spinner stop after the webview is finished loading but the `'did-finish-load'` event fires twice - this causes a blank page for couple of seconds.

Does anyone has a clue why?

I looked the documentation again but this is not explained right. Is there an event that's triggered once after all resources are done downloading and are ready to show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `'did-finish-load'` event is triggered 2 times : when you load the about:blank, and when you use `loadURL()`.

To convince you, try this:

main.js :

```
const { BrowserWindow} = require('electron')
let win = new BrowserWindow({width: 1450, height: 1200})
win.webContents.on('did-finish-load', () => {
    console.log('finished to load ');
})
win.loadURL(`about:blank`)
```

Then you will notice that `did-finish-load` has been triggered!

That's why the event is triggered two times in your code.

Note that the important part here is the `webContents` EventEmitter, that is an attribute of both BrowserWindows and webviews. I used a BrowserWindow to keep the example minimal.